# Taking last row from list of rows having same time or values in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been working on R dataframes. It is Time-Series data. 
which contains following inputs:

Dataframe:

```
Id  Timestamp             Values
1   2019-08-01 00:25:49    1
2   2019-08-01 00:25:49    2
3   2019-08-01 00:25:49    3
4   2019-08-01 00:25:50    4
5   2019-08-01 00:25:50    5
6   2019-08-01 00:25:50    6
7   2019-08-01 00:25:51    6
........
10   2019-08-01 00:25:52    10
```

This my input data frame name df1_p.

I have tried following code to find the distinct values of the data:

`df1_p <- df1_p[!duplicated(df1_p$Timestamp), ]`

But i get following output:

```
Id  Timestamp             Values
1   2019-08-01 00:25:49    1
4   2019-08-01 00:25:50    4
7   2019-08-01 00:25:51    6
```

I.e first row of duplicated values.

Even i have tried using `distinct()` as well i get same results.

But i need my output to be in following way;

```
Id  Timestamp             Values
3   2019-08-01 00:25:49    3
6   2019-08-01 00:25:50    6
7   2019-08-01 00:25:51    6
```

i.e last row of duplicated value.

Can anyone help me out with this .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Reading `?duplicated` is helpful, as it points you to `fromLast=TRUE`